# Disable selected chosen options when it exists in database

Tags: laravel-5, jquery-chosen, multiple-select

How can I disable the multiple select options when the item already exists in the database? Here's my form so far. Each item was stored in the database per row. I am using Laravel 5.2. Thanks

```
<form class="profile-detail-specialist skills-form" role="form" id="edit-skills">
  <select name="service_skillsreq[]" class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
      @foreach($skills as $skill)
           <option value="$skill->skills_name">{{$skill->skills_name}}</option>
      @endforeach
           </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="skills-btn">
    <button>Cancel</button>
    {{csrf_field()}}
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to echo a ***disabled*** attribute to the option tag if the item exists in your database. Try:

```
<option value="$skill->skills_name" <?php if(*database check*){echo"disabled";} ?>
 {{$skill->skills_name}}
</option>
```

Kindly replace the database check to an appropriate condition checking as I do not know the structure of your database.

Hope it helps =)